# Expanded navigation in Books

Tags: routes, navigation, nodes

By default the navigation in books is collapsed:

- **Fruits**
- **Vegetables**

Is there any way to make them expanded, so that the entire tree would be visible?

- **Fruits**

  - Apples
  - Bananas
- **Vegetables**

  - Tomatoes
  - Cucumbers
  - Carrots

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BookTree](https://www.drupal.org/project/booktree) module does the job. Some details from its project page:

> A simple tree presentation of one book.
>
> What it does is to take as input a series of Book nodes and create a tree-like structure using Book node relationships.
>
> Usage of the module is quite simple and flexible, and options exist to set the root node, the tree depth and to shorten long titles.

The [BookTree Example](http://uccio.org/booktree) contains a demo of it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module allows this. When you create a new menu block you get an option to select book as a menu. More details from its project page:

> So… have you ever used the Main and Secondary menu links feature on your theme and wondered “how the hell do I display any menu items deeper than that?”
>
> Well, that’s what this module does. It provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu. And more!
>
> So if you’re only using your theme’s Main menu links feature, you can add and configure a “Main menu (levels 2+)” block. That block would appear once you were on one of the Main menu’s pages and would show the menu tree for the 2nd level (and deeper) of your Main menu and would expand as you traversed down the tree. You can also limit the depth of the menu’s tree (e.g. “Main menu (levels 2-3)”) and/or expand all the child sub-menus (e.g. “Main menu (expanded levels 2+)”).